# Laravel Migration with data manipulation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I have a database with 3 tables that need to be migrated:

`processes`: contains data about a process

```
process_id - Id of the process
step_1_data - data about step 1
step_2_data - data about step 2
step_3_data - data about step 3
```

`file_process`: is a many to many relationship to files for that process

```
process_id - required foreign key to process
file_id - required foreign key to file
file_label - label of the file step
```

`files`: is a generic file table

```
file_id - Id of the file
name - name of the file
... lots of other file data
```

This is what I want:

`processes`: contains data about a process

```
process_id - Id of the process
```

`steps`: is a many to many relationship to files for that process

```
step_id - Id of the step
process_id - required foreign key to process
name - the name of the step (from column of step 1, 2, 3, and file_label)
data - data about step 1, 2, 3 (in different records)
file_id - nullable foreign key to file
```

`files`: is a generic file table (stays the same)

```
file_id - Id of the file
name - name of the file
... lots of other file data
```

I can make a migration that will change the steps table into a generic steps table with step information. However, I need to make a one time migration of the current process records, in order to make step records based on where that process is in the ... process :P

Raw DB queries don't seem like a good option since I need to do different things base on what stage in the process they are at.

What is the best way to make a migration that also contains data manipulation as well as schema manipulation in Laravel?

Comment: it'd be helpful if you could post your: (a) table schema; (b) example of the original data; (c) expected structure after migration. although i believe, [Blueprint](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html) did not have any api to do data manipulation.

Comment: mm don't seem to understand.. the `file_steps` table is the intermediate table (for the `many-to-many` relationship) of `process` and `files`? Also, follow the recomendation of @BagusTesa.

Comment: could this help https://github.com/nWidart/DbExporter?

Comment: @HCK that is correct. However, I would like to rename it to be steps, the label would become the step name. Step data from the process table would be moved to the steps table.

Comment: @BagusTesa done. I can't post data because of privacy concerns. Hopefully it's easy to extrapolate the data based on my explanation of the schema, let me know. TY

Comment: hmm, i think you will need at least two table, one to hold the data temporarily, and the other to be populated, copies everything to the temporary, then put back everything together using seeder.. i don't think there is an easy way..